# How to differentiate between multiple inputs with the same class inside loop using jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am using the following jQuery to add and take away increments of `1` into an input box.

```
$(function(){
    $('button.quantity-increment').on('click', function(){
        var form = $(this).closest('form');
        if($(this).hasClass('quantity-left-minus')){
            form.find('input.quantity').val(parseInt(form.find('input.quantity').val()) - 1);
        } else {
            form.find('input.quantity').val(parseInt(form.find('input.quantity').val()) + 1);
        }
        $('a.add_to_cart_variable').attr('data-quantity', form.find('input.quantity').val());
        logDataQuantityAttribute();
    });

    form.find('input.quantity').on('keyup', function(){
        $('a.add_to_cart_variable').attr('data-quantity', this.value);
        logDataQuantityAttribute();
    });
});
```

The form below is inside of a *Wordpress* loop. So when I click the plus and minus increment buttons currently it changes all of the input values.

Is there anyway to just increment the input inside the same form as the plus and minus glyphs are in?

```
<form class="cart-num" action="index.html" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-control input-number quantity" value="1" min="1" max="100">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="quantity-left-minus quantity-increment btn btn-number"  data-type="minus" data-field="">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
        </button>
    </span>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="quantity-right-plus quantity-increment btn btn-number" data-type="plus" data-field="">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
        </button>
    </span>
</form>
```

Comment: There is one major rule you need to follow.  When ever you are dealing with multiple elements you should not use id, **Use Class** to make life easier. Right now I can understand that your HTML has *multiple inputs with the same id 'quantity'* which is a **BIG NO**. Remove the Id's and add the `"quantity"` string in the class. Then instead of `$('input#quantity')` you can do `$(this).closest('form').find('input.quantity')`. let me know if this is unclear

Comment: An `input` element should have a `name` property

Comment: A `button` element cannot be inside a `span` element, and you do not need a `span` element inside the `button` element. just put the classes for the icon on the button itself. That said, your **event** should be on the `button` and not `span` inside it.

Comment: could you please response to the answer so that i can know it is working for you. And if it satisfies your problem then vote it up and mark it green else tell me if i need to change or add anything else.

Comment: I updated the question to add in some of your changes with classes etc. It is now working except when I scroll down to say product number 2 or 3 if I press the plus or minus it increments all of them still, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have mentioned that `The form below is inside of a Wordpress loop` so i think that the id will be repeated for the form elements. So it is a bad idea to set your JQuery logic by referencing the `id` of the element. Thus you can use this code to be on the safe side:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.quantity-right-plus').click(function(e){
    // Stop acting like a button
   e.preventDefault();
    var inputField = $(this).closest('form').find('input[type="text"]');
   // Get its current value
    var currentVal = parseInt($(inputField).val());
    
   // If is not undefined
   if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
       // Increment
       $(inputField).val(currentVal + 1);
   } else {
       // Otherwise put a 0 there
       $(inputField).val(0);
   }
 });


 $(".quantity-left-minus").click(function(e) {
     // Stop acting like a button
    e.preventDefault();
     //get the text field to be changed
     var inputField = $(this).closest('form').find('input[type="text"]');
     
        // Get its current value
   var currentVal = parseInt($(inputField).val());
   // If it isn't undefined or its greater than 0
   if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
       // Decrement one
       $(inputField).val(currentVal - 1);
   } else {
       // Otherwise put a 0 there
       $(inputField).val(0);
   }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="cart-num" action="index.html" method="post">
            <input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity" class="form-control input-number" value="1" min="1" max="100">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="quantity-left-minus btn btn-number"  data-type="minus" data-field="">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus">-</span>
        </button>
    </span>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="quantity-right-plus btn btn-number" data-type="plus" data-field="">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">+</span>
        </button>
    </span>
</form>
```

You can notice that i have used `input[type="text"]` as a selector to find the element. Not an `id` as in loop this `id` will be same and will give you incorrect result if you reference the element by `id` in your JQuery code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way use jquery `selectors`, first of all

Select form of clicked glyphicon with:

```
$('span.glyphicon').on('click', function(){
   var form = $(this).parents('form.cart-num');
});
```

Then you can do finding within form, and increment only input within this form.

```
$(function(){
    $('span.glyphicon').on('click', function(){
        var form = $(this).parents('form.cart-num');
        if($(this).hasClass('glyphicon-minus')){
            form.find('input#quantity').val(parseInt(form.find('input#quantity').val()) - 1);
        } else {
            form.find('input#quantity').val(parseInt(form.find('input#quantity').val()) + 1);
        }
        $('a.add_to_cart_variable').attr('data-quantity', form.find('input#quantity').val());
        logDataQuantityAttribute();
    });

    $('input#quantity').on('keyup', function(){
        $('a.add_to_cart_variable').attr('data-quantity', this.value);
        logDataQuantityAttribute();
    });
});
```

**Working example:**

```js
$(function(){
    $('span.glyphicon').on('click', function(){
        var form = $(this).parents('form.cart-num');
        if($(this).hasClass('glyphicon-minus')){
            form.find('input').val(parseInt(form.find('input').val()) - 1);
        } else {
            form.find('input').val(parseInt(form.find('input').val()) + 1);
        }
        //$('a.add_to_cart_variable').attr('data-quantity', form.find('input').val());
        //logDataQuantityAttribute();
    });

    $('input#quantity').on('keyup', function(){
        //$('a.add_to_cart_variable').attr('data-quantity', this.value);
        logDataQuantityAttribute();
    });
});
```

```css
button { padding: 0px; border: none; background: transparent; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="cart-num" action="index.html" method="post">
            <input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity" class="form-control input-number" value="1" min="1" max="100">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="quantity-left-minus btn btn-number"  data-type="minus" data-field="">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus">-</span>
        </button>
    </span>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="quantity-right-plus btn btn-number" data-type="plus" data-field="">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">+</span>
        </button>
    </span>
</form>
<form class="cart-num" action="index.html" method="post">
            <input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity" class="form-control input-number" value="1" min="1" max="100">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="quantity-left-minus btn btn-number"  data-type="minus" data-field="">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus">-</span>
        </button>
    </span>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="quantity-right-plus btn btn-number" data-type="plus" data-field="">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">+</span>
        </button>
    </span>
</form>
```